# facebook link not recognise as gif

Tags: facebook, gif

I try to upload the link of animated gif image which stored in AWS S3 buckets to facebook message and recognise as animated gif image. 
I successfully work with direct S3 link e.g.
https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.example.com/abc.gif
However, when i want to use my own sub domain name, facebook just can recognise as a link , but NOT GIF Image. 
https://media.examples.com/abc.gif

May i ask how can get "recognise as animated gif image" by facebook?

Comment: You need to compare the response headers you get from both links. I'm going to guess that the one not playing well with Facebook is sending an incorrect Content-Type header

Comment: i already checked the header respond, Content-Type both are "image/gif" , also the "Server" also can recognise as "AmazonS3"

Answer (score 1):

I got exactly the opposite problem.
amazon S3 bucket are Not reconized as gif ( just a link inside FB)

https://camcam360.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/camcam_lancement_commercial/1609106_222137__finalpourdevraiauchocolat/1609106_222137__finalpourdevraiauchocolat.gif

but
gif from my web site are reconize as gif (gif inside FB)
https://www.adebeo.com/tmp/1609106_222137__finalpourdevraiauchocolat.gif

On Amazon cors setup of the bucket are like that

> *
>           GET
>           3000
>           Authorization

folder have standard folder and no-standard encryption

Permission on my website is 604

-----> finaly I solve the problem by specify the type in the metaadta of the S3.bucket.objet as image/gif